# How to make Firefox prefer images to HTML?

Tags: browser, format, web, user-agent

Sometimes when you follow an image URL, it will take you to a web page containing the image instead of only showing the image.  Then, when you you right click and select Open Image in New Tab, it will again take you to the same web page.

So clearly the image URL returns an image, not a web page, otherwise you wouldn't be able to see the image at all, you would just see the web page recursively.

I assumed that these sites (such as Reddit) were using some clever trick to make this happen, so I decide to dig in.  It actually seems they're not using any trick at all, they're just honoring the preferences your user-agent (browser) is sending with the request:

```
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
```

So Firefox seems to be telling websites that it would prefer to see an HTML page (HTML/XML is considered 90% "quality") to an image (considered 80% "quality").

Am I understanding that correctly and, if so, how do I change this to prefer just the image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in the advanced configuration available in Firefox.

1. Enter `about:config` in the address bar and accept the warning when prompted.
2. In the search box put "accept"
3. You should see, among other options, `network.http.accept` and `image.http.accept`
4. If the boxes are blank then copy in your line and add `image/*;0.9` to the comma separated list (i also adjusted the values for html/xml down) For me this became

   ```
   image/*;0.9,text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.8,image/avif,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
   ```

   I did this for both `network.http.accept` and `image.http.accept`

After changing this line Reddit stopped serving web pages and gave me the actual image.

Comment: How does Firefox pick which of `network.http.accept` or `image.http.accept` to send? I changed only the latter, and Reddit is now showing images both when I click "Open Image in New Tab" and when I enter the URL of the image.

Comment: Also, is there any reason you accept `image/*`, then HTML/XML, then `image/avif,image/webp`?  I just put all the image types together on the left.

Comment: @Zaz I set both during testing just in case the server ignored the "image" accept settings, likewise the slightly off order was because I was just testing, I would expect the `image/avif` to get essentially ignored as it's already covered and likely overridden by `image/*`. I meant to come back and do some testing and tidy up but got distracted.